# Опечатка в сообщении об успешном прохождении проверки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

1. В [очереди проверок сообщениий от новичков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/75891) нажал на «Действия не требуются».

   [Высокого качество http://pokit.org/get/img/c6270b1cac4318d2d5246bb8e60df2af.jpg](http://pokit.org/get/img/c6270b1cac4318d2d5246bb8e60df2af.jpg)

   Высокого качеств**а**.
2. Там же вторая строка начинается со строчной буквы, а должна с заглавной.
3. "Вашу", "Вашей" с заглавной буквы не нужно.
4. Сейчас по той же ссылке не согласовано число:

> Проверк*и* прошла аудит 1 час назад:

Comment: Добавил ещё три ошибки с той же страницы )

Comment: Вашу — [не ошибка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/51-rubric-88). «Местоимения Вы и Ваш пишутся с прописной (большой) буквы как форма вежливого обращения к одному лицу. При обращении к нескольким лицам следует писать вы и ваш со строчной буквы. Написание Вы, Ваш с прописной при обращении к нескольким лицам – ошибка.» В нашем случае обращение ведётся к одному лицу. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных: У нас было обсуждение по этому поводу. Мы решили, что «Вы» с прописной буквы — слишком пафосно и по-канцелярски, и с того момента последовательно пишем со строчной.

Comment: @VladD, согласно правилам и [официальному ответу Института русского языка РАН](http://web.archive.org/web/20081022205917/www.yandex.ru/info/you_full.html) употребление «вы» со строчной буквы при обращении к одному лицу, возможно, даже ошибочно. «Окончательное решение о написании Вы с прописной (для подчеркивания этого уважительного отношения) принимает автор текста.» — почему бы не подчеркнуть уважительное отношение к пользователям Stack Overflow?

Comment: @СашаЧерных: Но в процитированном [вВ]ами документе как раз и предлагается оформлять обращение в интернете со строчной буквы. (Финальный абзац.)

Comment: @VladD, не дочитал до конца, виноват.

Comment: Ещё одна опечатка: `Это сообщение высокого качествО`.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, это же в п.1 указано. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Не доглядел, извините.

Comment: Сейчас сообщение звучит несколько механически. Как насчёт того, чтобы переписать его целиком? Например, сделать заголовком `Вы прошли проверку`. И затем пояснить: `Чтобы оценить вашу внимательность, мы добавили в очередь сообщение высокого качества. Вы правильно его оценили, поздравляем!`

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, сейчас кроме меня, как автора темы, никто Ваши комментарии не видит. Т. к. она уже устарела, вряд ли много кто сюда посмотрит. Чтобы привлечь внимание сообщества, пожалуйста, создавайте новые темы. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Спасибо за совет. Сделал. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2994/

Comment: Про Вы/вы в интерфейсе сайта: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3318/ и http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489/

Comment: Про "качество" говорят, [исправлено](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3599/176217).