# Переписать сообщение об успешной проверке на внимательность

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок, аудит

Сейчас сообщение звучит несколько механически. Как будто оно склеено из разрозненных кусочков.

> **Поздравляем!**
>
> Это всего лишь проверка, чтобы оценить Вашу внимательность. Вы прошли
>   проверку. Это сообщение высокого качество, результаты Вашей проверки
>   оказались верными.

Рядом есть [тема про опечатки в этом сообщении](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2881/), но как насчёт того, чтобы переписать его целиком?

Comment: Вам большое спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Что дальше? Отмечать свой ответ как принятый и звать тех, кто может изменить сообщение? Как это сделать?

Comment: Следует отметить принятым наиболее популярный ответ. Далее я обновлю базу строк. Новый перевод станет доступным после следующей развёртки сборки.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Отметил.

Comment: Как мне кажется, у нас есть небольшие затруднения. Строка собирается из нескольких, как результат, мы не можем менять порядок строк в фразе и значение самой фразы. Изначально идет [поздравление](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265383), затем [пояснение, что это проверка, и ее результат](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265390), а в завершении [говориться о типе проверки](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265389).

Comment: С большой вероятностью, фраза собирается динамически.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Насколько понимаю, нужен доступ к Транзифексу, чтобы разобраться в конструкторе сообщений. По совету Николая Волынкина, [сделал заявку на доступ](https://www.transifex.com/user/profile/glebkema/), но она пока ждёт своего часа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Получил доступ, спасибо. Как узнать, где ещё используются эти три фрагмента (поздравление, пояснение и обозначение типа проверки)?

Comment: Никак. И это самая большая проблема текущей локализации. Про каждую строку надо трясти разработчиков и смотреть в код.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Вы прошли проверку**
>
> Чтобы проверить вашу внимательность, мы добавили в очередь сообщение
>   высокого качества. Вы правильно его оценили, поздравляем!

Comment: Там действительно составное сообщение. Из нескольких кусков формируются сообщения для всевозможных проверок. Если уж переписывать, то сразу все компоненты.

Comment: А в целом предложение мне нравится и новая формулировка хороша. )

Comment: Заметил, что дважды повторяется глагол "оценить". У меня два варианта для исправления первого из них - `Чтобы проверить` и `Чтобы испытать`. Поскольку цель сообщения - быть понятным без перечитывания, склоняюсь к `Чтобы проверить`. Оно повторяет заголовок, подчёркивая свой поясняющий характер. Но четверо уже проголосовали. Как лучше поступить?

Comment: Заменил первое "оценить" на "проверить".

Comment: @NickVolynkin Расскажите, как устроена сборка сообщений из компонентов? Какими должны быть сообщения, чтобы их можно было загрузить в систему? (Или про это лучше новую тему создать?)

Comment: Оставьте заявку на доступ в Transifex - увидите. Постараюсь сегодня найти время и сюда выложить все части.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Отправил заявку в Transifex.