# Как совместить русскую речь с механикой Транзифекса?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

Сайт собирает сообщения из фрагментов. У каждого фрагмента - своё предназначение. Например, [сообщение о проверке на внимательность](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2994/) собирается из трёх частей:

1. заголовка, обозначающего успех или неудачу;
2. пояснения, что произошла проверка, и её результата;
3. пояснения о типе проверке и её результате.

Чтобы предлагать новые переводы сообщений, нужно:

1. исследовать, как сайт использует фрагменты из Транзифекса (где ещё задействован этот заголовок, сколько сообщений имеют аналогичную структуру и т.п.);
2. поменять назначение фрагментов, чтобы итоговые сообщения звучали по-русски.

Что уже сделано по этой части? Что нужно учесть? Как организовать работу?

Comment: Есть [страница пропущенных строк перевода](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2718). Конечно же, этого не достаточно. Сейчас ребята в команде обдумывают, как можно улучшить существующую систему (но без создания аналога Transifex). Если у вас есть какие–либо идеи, буду рад выслушать!

Answer (score 2):

На текущий момент перевод интерфейса сайта работает через цепочку [ru.tradicir.win](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8256/176217) → transifex.com. Далее строки подгружаются в движок при каждой пересборке, происходящей обычно по несколько раз в течение рабочего дня. Любой участник ruSO может предложить перевод той или иной фразы (как не имеющей перевода, так и исправление/улучшение по текущему переводу). Далее, участники с полномочиями редактора (reviewer в терминологии traducir) утверждают, отклоняют или адаптируют перевод, если первичный переводчик чего-то не учёл.

Искать предварительно все возможные вхождения тех или иных подстрок не является необходимым. Ничего страшного не случится, если сайт побудет несколько дней с кривыми переводами (ведь жил же он так несколько лет уже). В случае обнаружения нестыковок стоит завести вопрос на Мете с метками [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) и [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f). Ситуацию рассмотрят заинтересованные участники и попробуют предложить подходящее решение, или же можно будет перекинуть ответственность за решение проблемы на большого брата ([Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)), если обычным переводом не получается ограничиться.

А ещё, не так давно, КМ хвастался, что у него есть инструмент, позволяющий по исходной строке найти место (страницу сайта), где эта строка используется. Очень было бы хорошо иметь такой тул в общем пользовании для всех, заинтересованных в локализации сайта, а не только для сотрудников компании. Не знаю, возможно ли это на данном этапе.

Comment: А напомните страницу с недостающими переводами?

Comment: @Suvitruf она уже [не работает](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323989/339911).

Comment: Помню, я сам уже в чате у них спрашивал не раз. Нужно ещё разок )