# Мы переходим на Traducir.win для перевода интерфейса сайта!

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, traducir

Две недели назад [я предложил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8188/) использовать дополнительный инструмент Traducir для перевода интерфейса сайта. Traducir — это проект с открытым исходным кодом, который был создан ребятами из Stack Overflow на испанском. Приложение работает как надстройка над Transifex. Негативных отзывов предложение не получило, в том же время преимущества у него определенно есть (те же уведомления, возможность отмечать срочными к переводу и т.д.) Давайте пробовать!?

Пожалуйста, будьте внимательны:

> В выходные, 17 — 18 ноября 2018 года, [@g3rv4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/238921/g3rv4?tab=profile) активирует для русскоязычного сообщества Traducir.

Это означает, что все переводы внесенные на Transifex начиная с вечера пятницы могут быть потеряны. Пожалуйста, подождите активации Traducir для нашего сообщества и используйте его для переводов.

Мы запускаем Traducir в экспериментальном режиме, который продлится месяц. В течении этого времени сообществу предстоит определиться, хотим ли мы и далее работать с Traducir или стоит вернуться к Transifex. Пожалуйста, используйте Traducir как можно больше! Это позволит сделать правильный выбор.

Comment: А почему в предыдущем посте опрос ответами не запилили? Отсутствие "негативных отзывов" ещё ничего не означает же.

Comment: `Could not retrieve a user account on es.stackoverflow.com` - чтобы им пользоваться, надо на esSO регистрироваться?

Comment: @Qwertiy Для нашего сообщества еще не развернули приложение. Скорее всего будет к понедельнику.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, о, спасибо! А я тут уже успел [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8260/178988) рядом задать. Я почему-то думал, что это универсальная обёртка над транзифексом, а оказывается надо отдельно для каждого сайта разворачивать.

Comment: Затестил, действительно хорошая система. Думаю не зря перешли на traducir :)

Comment: IP-адрес сайта traducir.win внесён в реестр Роскомнадзора и недоступен для некоторых пользователей: «[traducir.win доступ к сайту ограничен провайдером](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8521/208074)».

Comment: @Arhad Большое спасибо! Не очевидно, что теперь лучше сделать.

Answer (score 15):

Sorry that I'm writing in English, but I speak 0 Russian (I'm attaching a translation with Google, but feel free to fix it).

I've just finished setting everything up on Traducir so that it handles translations for SOru :) you can visit [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win) to access it (your account here should be enough to log you in, there's no need to register anywhere).

This was built by the community in SOes because we were pretty frustrated with the way translations worked for us. It's using the Transifex API and **rewriting everything there every 10 minutes**. That means that while we have it enabled, you shouldn't do any translations on Transifex.

The source of truth for translations is ru.traducir.win. The entire thing is open source, so if there's something you'd like it to have you can [open an issue](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/issues) and build it!

If you want to discuss implementation details, we can do so at GitHub or on [this chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1247/traducir-win).

We're lacking lots of documentation (so if you want to write it, it's more than welcome!) but here's a description of what it does:

- Every 10 minutes, it pulls strings from Transifex (to get the latest ones). Here *it ignores deletions for a while* (since there's a bug on SO that deletes strings from time to time)
- Every 10 minutes, it pushes **all the translated strings** to transifex

That's on the background. Now, what you see:

- You can log in with your SOru account
- You can perform regular expression searches both in the original text as in the translated text (searches are by default case sensitive... if you want to perform a case insensitive search, you should add `(?i)` as a prefix)
- You can suggest a translation for a string
- You can mark a string as urgent (if you see it untranslated on the site)
- Trusted users (defined by the mods) can reject or pre-approve strings (so that reviewers have a cleaner list of things to do)
- Reviewers (the site mods) can either approve or reject strings. Once they do so, they're pushed to Transifex
- You can be notified (via web push notifications) of a bunch of things. Log in and click on "Notifications"

A CM needs to manually import the translations from Transifex to the codebase (this is exactly as it was before traducir). But now, the CM can also be notified via web push notifications when that needs to happen.

Do you want to see what's in the database? You can query the live database at [db.traducir.win](https://db.traducir.win) (find the credentials [here](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/blob/master/docs/USING_REDASH.md)) The system does two backups per day (and they can be downloaded at [db-backups.traducir.win](http://db-backups.traducir.win/)). There you can access all the string and suggestions history. Do you want to see the source code? sure! [It's here!](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir).

Anyway, this was built by our community to solve our community's problems (check [our initial meta post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/11272) in Spanish). I would love to see it help other international communities... if you'd like to help, that would be amazing.

If it doesn't fit SOru's needs, then no big deal :) we will disable it and go back to Transifex.

---

Сообщение было переведено с помощью Google Translate. Не стесняйтесь его редактировать :)

Я только что закончил настройку Traducir так, чтобы он обрабатывал переводы для SOru :) вы можете посетить [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win) для доступа к нему (вашей учетной записи здесь должно быть достаточно для входа в систему, нет необходимости регистрироваться в другом месте).

Это было разработано сообществом в SOes, потому что мы были очень расстроены тем, как переводы работали у нас. Он использует API Transifex и **переписывает все там каждые 10 минут**. Это означает, что, пока он включен, вы не должны делать переводы на Transifex.

Первоначальным источником для переводов является ru.traducir.win. Надстройка с открытым исходным кодом, поэтому, если есть какие-то пожелания, вы можете [заводить замечания](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/issues) !

Если вы хотите обсудить детали реализации, мы можем сделать это на GitHub или в [этом чате](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1247/traducir-win).

Нам не хватает документации (поэтому, если вы хотите написать ее, это более чем приветствуется!). Вот описание того, что происходит в данный момент:

- Каждые 10 минут он вытягивает строки из Transifex (чтобы получить последние). Здесь он игнорирует удаления в течение некоторого времени (поскольку на SO есть ошибка, которая время от времени удаляет строки)
- Каждые 10 минут он пушит **все переведенные строки** в transifex

Это на бэкэнде. Теперь, что вы видите:

- Вы можете войти с помощью своей учетной записи на SOru
- Вы можете выполнять поиск регулярных выражений как в исходном тексте, так и в переведенном тексте (поиск по умолчанию чувствителен к регистру ... если вы хотите выполнить поиск без учета регистра, вы должны добавить `(?i)` в качестве префикса)
- Вы можете предложить перевод для строки
- Вы можете отметить строку как срочную (если вы видите ее непереведенной на сайте)
- Надежные пользователи (определенные модераторами) могут отклонять или предварительно утверждать строки (чтобы у рецензентов был более чистый todo-список)
- Рецензенты (модераторы сайта) могут либо утверждать, либо отклонять строки. Как только они это сделают, их переводят в Transifex
- Вы можете получать уведомления (через веб-оповещения) о множестве вещей. Войдите в систему и нажмите «Уведомления».

CM необходимо вручную импортировать переводы из Transifex в кодовую базу (это точно так же, как и до traducir). Но теперь CM также может быть уведомлен через веб-push-уведомления, когда это должно произойти.

Вы хотите узнать, что находится в базе данных? Вы можете запросить текущую базу данных на странице [db.traducir.win](https://db.traducir.win) (найдите учетные данные [здесь](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir/blob/master/docs/USING_REDASH.md)) Система выполняет две резервные копии в день (и их можно загрузить на [db-backups.traducir.win](http://db-backups.traducir.win/)). Там вы можете получить доступ ко всей истории строк и предложений. Вы хотите увидеть исходный код? конечно! [Это здесь!](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir).

Во всяком случае, это было построено нашим сообществом для решения проблем нашего сообщества (прочитайте [наш исходный мета-пост](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/11272) на испанском языке). Я хотел бы, чтобы это помогло другим международным сообществам ... если бы вы хотели помочь, это было бы потрясающе.

Если это не соответствует потребностям SOru, тогда нечего делать :) мы отключим его и вернемся к Transifex.