# Как залогиниться в traducir.win?

Tags: поддержка, локализация, traducir

Вроде как [переходим](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8256/178988) на новый инструмент - хотел заглянуть, что там как, но когда нажимаю кнопку Log in, получаю сообщение об ошибке:

> Could not retrieve a user account on es.stackoverflow.com

неужели для его использования надо регистрироваться на esSO?

Comment: >"В выходные, **17 — 18 ноября 2018 года**, @g3rv4 активирует для русскоязычного сообщества Traducir." 17 ноября еще не наступило

Answer (score 5):

You can log in now at [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win) :)

---

Вы можете войти в систему на [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win) :)

Comment: Yep, it works! :)