# traducir.win доступ к сайту ограничен провайдером

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, traducir

Сегодня, зайдя на сайт [ru.traducir.win](http://ru.traducir.win), узнал, что теперь доступ к сайту ограничен провайдером. Пока ни url ни ip в базе реестра не находится.

> Уважаемые пользователи! Приносим свои извинения, доступ к
>   информационному ресурсу ограничен на основании Федерального закона от
>   27 июля 2006 г. № 149-ФЗ «Об информации, информационных технологиях и
>   защите информации»

Данная проблема встречается у провайдеров Ростелеком и NetByNet (Wifire), Ростовская область. У кого еще такая проблема? Что думаете по этому поводу?

Если сайт заблокирован по ошибке (заблокировали ip и его просто зацепило), то может администрация SO рассмотрит вариант о смене ip сайта?

**UPD:** записи в реестре появились, что примечательно внесли в реестр аж 13.04.2018

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD: 08.12.2019** Сайт опять недоступен

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: traducir.win [размещён на CloudFlare](https://viewdns.info/dnsrecord/?domain=traducir.win). Так что надо не IP менять, а хостинг.

Comment: И да, у меня открывается (`159.65.67.51` десять раз подряд). СПб, провайдер — Уют Телеком. Также `tracert` показывает транзит через РАСКОМ и Stockholm Customer Links, если надо отыскать блокирующий узел.

Comment: Так что в качестве временной меры можно прописать в `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` строку `159.65.67.51 traducir.win` и перезагрузиться.

Comment: Подтверждаю: `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Comment: @Arhad, так блокировка по ip, твой вариант тоже не открывается.

Comment: @Arhad заблокировали ip 159.65.67.51, в реестре теперь он есть.

Comment: как это относится к нам?

Comment: @michael_best https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8256/Мы-переходим-на-traducir-win-для-перевода-интерфейса-сайта?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: судя по всему этот ip *один из многих* пострадавших в битве за телеграм, (провайдер telenet пока все работает)

Comment: У меня из дома не пашет, в офисе иногда работает. Провайдер onlime.

Comment: @Suvitruf калифорнийский? :)

Comment: @älёxölüt если бы. Я ж в Мск нынче =/

Comment: @Suvitruf странно, что миграционная служба мне не доложила о возвращении :)

Comment: @älёxölüt недоработочка :D

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Тоже недавно заметил проблему с доступом, но подумал, что она локальная для моего интернет–провайдера. Сейчас захожу на сайт с помощью VPN–компании. Проблема очень досадная. Как её решить наиболее правильно, не ясно. Буду благодарен за любые советы и рекомендации.

Comment: @Qwertiy а что проблему уже решили? У меня сайт до сих пор недоступен.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, у меня открывается.  А всё, понял. У меня по ipv6 открывается. Убираю метку.

Comment: @Qwertiy думаю можно закрыть, сайт открывается нормально.