# Перевод сообщения о правке, поставленной в очередь проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, предлагаемые-правки

При редакции вопроса появляется сообщение:

> Ваша правка будет поставлена в очередь, пока не пройдёт экспертную проверку.
>
> We welcome edits that make the post easier to understand and more
> valuable for readers. Because community members review edits, please
> try to make the post substantially better than how you found it, for
> example, by fixing grammar or adding additional resources and
> hyperlinks.

Переведите пожалуйста

Comment: Вы всегда можете предложить свой перевод на ru.traducir.com Подробнее [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8256/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ или хотя бы здесь ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/string/12045):

> Мы приветствуем правки, которые позволяют проще понять сообщение и делают его более полезным для читателей. Так как члены сообщества проверяют правки, пожалуйста, постарайтесь сделать сообщение существенно лучше, чем оно было, когда вы нашли его, например, путём исправления грамматики или добавления дополнительных ресурсов и ссылок.

Будет на сайте после подкачки и пересборки.