# Обновили дизайн, а перевод нет

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, вопросы

Не солидно, надо бы перевести)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выкатились переводы.

Comment: @Suvitruf увидел)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавил строки:

1. https://ru.traducir.win/string/12975

   > Вопрос задан
2. https://ru.traducir.win/string/12970

   > Просмотрен
3. https://ru.traducir.win/string/12971

   > $viewsPretty$ раза
4. https://ru.traducir.win/string/12972

   > $viewsPretty$ раз
5. https://ru.traducir.win/string/12973

   > $viewsPretty$ раз
6. https://ru.traducir.win/string/12969

   > Последняя активность

Comment: `Active` потерялось?

Comment: @Qwertiy благодарю. Добавил.

Comment: Простите за глупость, а что это за инструмент?

Comment: @doox911 это сервис для совместного перевода SOru.

Comment: Я могу предложить свой? Или если заметил косяк тут подправить? А ссылку как брать?

Comment: @doox911 если есть доступ, можете там предложить. Но лучше сначала тут в ответах предложить )

Comment: А кому предоставляется доступ?

Comment: @doox911 попросить нужно. Не уверен, у кого сейчас. Скорей всего, либо у [Николая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6), либо у [αλεχολυτ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217)

Comment: @doox911 доступ может получить любой участник [самостоятельно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8256/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ спасибо за правку)