# Склонение во фразе "40 полезные тревоги"

Tags: предложение, локализация, тревоги, профиль-участника

"Участники" -> "Активность" -> "Сводка" -> "Влияние" -> "40 полезные тревоги". Неправильное склонение режет глаз. Это как-то можно поправить?

Comment: В локализации строка без типа множественного числа (many/few): https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17243 , видимо в этом и проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Там весь блок не имеет привязок к количественным значениям.

> [image: Блок влияния]

Поэтому не стоит рассматривать это как [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82). Просто такая упрощённая форма отображения. Для упрощения понимания сути, просто переставьте в уме текстовое описание перед цифрами и добавьте двоеточие как разделитель. Например,

> полезные тревоги: 814

Если же рассматривать ваш вопрос как [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), то нужно делать это в комплексе для всего блока "Влияние".

Создал соответствующий фича-реквест на MSE: [Add pluralization option to impact block related strings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374964/339911)

Comment: На этой странице таких мест много. Я посмотрел Web UI для локализации, там можно предлагать переводы. Но синтаксис не очень ясный. И не понятно как тестировать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy о каком Web UI речь?

Comment: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17243

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy чуть подробнее [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8256/176217).

Comment: Спасибо. Посмотрю.

Comment: Не знаю как внутрях, но с точки зрения пользователя это именно дефект.

Comment: @PavelMayorov если рассматривать надпись "814 полезные тревоги" как единое предложение, то дефект. Но в текущем дизайне это не является единым предложением. Это просто число и связанная с  ним категория. Т.е. вместо текущих фраз вполне могли бы быть "кол-во затронутых людей", "изменённые сообщения", "отданные голоса". Но мне не кажется это подходящим вариантом. Бесспорно, если добавить множественные формы, то можно сделать лучше даже при текущем дизайне. Но улучшение - это всегда [meta-tag:feature-request], а не [meta-tag:bug].

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вы уверены, что не стали роботом? Пройдите гуглокапчу на всякий, проверьте себя :-) Я вот, как человек, не могу не рассматривать "814 полезные тревоги" как единое предложение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov они на разных уровнях написаны и даже разным шрифтом. Сравните, например, с заголовком [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%ce%b1%ce%bb%ce%b5%cf%87%ce%bf%ce%bb%cf%85%cf%84?tab=answers). "575 ответов" - это единая строка, тут обязательно должно быть согласованно с числом. В случае с блоком "Влияние" это не так. Поэтому здесь возможны разные интерпретации.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а не важно сколько тут уровней и шрифтов, всё равно двумя отдельными предложениями оно звучит не по-русски

Comment: @PavelMayorov на самом деле это очень важно. Иначе можно было бы и про любое табличное представление так сказать, что оно не по-русски звучит.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ так ведь тут не таблица, вот в чём проблема

Comment: @PavelMayorov почему же не таблица? Вполне себе табличное представление с одной строкой и одним заголовком, просто бордер невидимый.