# "Посмотреть все 1 конкурс" не звучит. Надо адаптировать перевод

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника, конкурс

При единственном конкурсе в списке (в профиле пользователя) запись выглядит несколько странно:

> [image: Посмотреть все 1 конкурс]

Надо сделать красиво.

На английском с этим есть особенность: [Where can I look at English-English translations on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386953/339911)

Comment: А вот [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11854/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-40-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8) не про то же самое вопрос?

Comment: @Павел совершенно разные вещи. Тут "конкурс", там "влияние".

Comment: Я к тому, что если какой-то блок сайта решили реализовать без склонений, то, вероятно, и остальные блоки делаются по подобной логике

Comment: @Павел такой зависимости нет, к счастью :)

Comment: Посмотреть весь 1 конкурс 

Comment: @andreymal в текущем раскладе туда попадут и 21,31,41...

Comment: Учитывая, что количество конкурсов уже пишется в скобочках сверху - я думаю будет уместно заменить всю нижнюю фразу на "посмотреть все конкурсы"

Comment: @Павел идея хорошая, но, к сожалению,  в переводе нельзя убирать переменные. Т.е. число так или иначе должно присутствовать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ может быть тогда "Посмотреть все конкурсы (N)"?

Comment: @Павел это будет выглядеть почти как дублирование заголовка, кмк.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ да, но по крайней мере предложение будет согласовано :)

Comment: @Павел согласовано с кем или чем?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ согласовано по правилам русского языка (согласуется с главным (определяемым) словом в роде, числе и падеже).

Comment: @Павел предложенный в ответе вариант не согласован?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ для варианта `one` - все ок, а для остальных в числе остается не согласован, "посмотреть 2 конкурс", "посмотреть все 2 конкурс"

Comment: @Павел см [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1136/176217) про one/few/many

Comment: @αλεχολυτ тогда все ок, извиняюсь, изначально подумал, что исходная проблема топика формулировалась не только для `one`, но и для `few` и `many`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока сделал как "Посмотреть N конкурс".

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17273

т.е. убрал слово "все" для варианта one (1, 21, 31...). Не очень правильно, но лучше, чем было.

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2023.2.24.43259