# Не переведено новое сообщение о переносе комментариев в чат

Tags: дефект, локализация, перенос-комментариев-в-чат

[Автоматически сгенерированный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1492423/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-codewars/1492491#comment2675558_1492491) комментарий не переведён.

> [image: lorem ipsum dolor sit amet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил пару переводов:

- Для главного сайта
  https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18866
- Для Меты
  https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18864

Будут в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2023.2.2.43213

Answer (score 1):

Штош, могу порекомендовать следующий перевод, чтобы на пару минут облегчить работу локализатору)

> **Комментарии были перемещены в чат. Пожалуйста, не продолжайте обсуждение в этой ветке.** Перед тем, как опубликовать новый
> комментарий, пожалуйста, прочтите [о предназначении комментариев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
> Комментарии, которые не запрашивают пояснений и не предлагают правок, возможно,
> следует опубликовать [в виде ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), либо на [Stack Overflow на русском Meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com), либо в чате: [Чат Stack Overflow на русском](https://chat.stackexchange.com/).
> Комментарии, которые тем не менее продолжат обсуждения ниже, могут быть
> удалены.

Comment: Спасибо за усилия. Можно пробовать предлагать сразу на traducir.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а я не шарю за это XD

Comment: См. [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8256/176217)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а в ответе выше это ты добавил переводы?

Comment: Да. У меня есть такая возможность. И сразу утверждать, чтобы они попали в ближайшую сборку сайта. Обычные юзеры могут только предлагать, но утверждение за ревьювером.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну я не зря написал ответ выше, я хоть никогда здесь не переводил, но тем не менее: 1) "пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь" слишком дословно, у дискуссии есть перевод - обсуждение, 2) "Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого" опять же излишне дословный перевод, и так понятно что нельзя разместить комментарий ВЫШЕ этого, 3) "скорее всего должны быть [ответами]" - здесь точно не "скорее всего", а "как вариант - один из перечисленных: ответ/чат/мета" (в оригинале на англ фактическая ошибка); про дискуссию в конце также можно поменять, это слово переводится как обсуждение

Comment: Вот "ошибка в оригинале" - это очень плохо. Это значит, что строка поменяется и надо обновлять перевод после этого в любом случае. Дотюнить же перевод - не проблема. О необходимости пофиксить оригинал на английском стоит и вовсе на MSE написать. Сделаешь? :)